# Most efficient way to read fragmented binary data from file and split it into several vectors. C++

Tags: c++, vector, binaryfiles

I face following problem; I have to read binary data from a file into several different vectors. Unfortunately the data in the file is aligned differently
as i would need it in my vectors.

Example: ( V1.1 = Vector1 Value 1, V2.4 = Vector 2 Value 4)

File Layout:
Number of Vectors is known, Size of File is known, and Number
of Values is known.

V1.1 V2.1 V3.1 V4.1 V1.2 V2.2 V3.2 V4.2 V1.3 V2.3 V3.3 V4.3 ....

These files can contain hundreds of megabyte of data, so if i only
read small chunks out of it and split that into my vectors (std::copy)
it takes too much time.

Thanks in advance,
Nico

Below some "meta-code":
As the single values can be of different types i first calculate the
chunk size, and the single datatype lengths, then i directly read the
single values into the target vector, which then is back_inserted into
an different vector. (the final Append data has to do several additional
things which i really do not want to call often).

```
void readSimpleTypeInterleaved( rawDataBlock *rawDataBlock)  // this will be called multiple times for a single file
{
   unsigned int iChunkSize(0);
   std::vector< std::vector<BYTE> > aVectorOfData(rawDataBlock-    >numVectorDataCount);
   std::vector <unsigned int> vByteSizeVector(rawDataBlock->numVectorDataCount);

   fileStream().seekg( rawDataBlock->start, ios_base::beg);

   for(unsigned int i=0;i<rawDataBlock->numVectorDataCount;++i)
   {
      unsigned int iTypeSize = rawDataBlock->GetChannelDataSize(i);
      vByteSizeVector[i] = iTypeSize;
      iChunkSize += iTypeSize;
      aVectorOfData[i].reserve(  (rawDataBlock->byteLength / iTypeSize) / rawDataBlock->numChannels); // rough estimation (as block does sometimes contain different types
   }
   iChunkSize *= rawDataBlock->numOfElements;

   for (unsigned iCurrBytePosition=0; iCurrBytePosition < rawDataBlock-    >byteLength; iCurrBytePosition += chunkSize)
    {
        for (int iActualValue = 0; iActualValue < rawDataBlock->numOfElements; ++iActualValue)
        {
            for (unsigned int channel = 0; channel < rawDataBlock-    >numVectorDataCount; ++channel)
            {
                unsigned int iTypeSize(vByteSizeVector[channel]);
                unsigned int iVectorSize(aVectorOfChannelData[channel].size());
                aVectorOfChannelData[channel].resize(iVectorSize + iTypeSize);
                fileStream().readIntoVectorAt(aVectorOfChannelData[channel], iVectorSize, iTypeSize);
                // this is ifstream::read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&aVectorOfChannelData[channel][iVectorSize]), iTypeSize);
            }
        }
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rawDataBlock->numVectorDataCount; ++i)
    {
        pFile->AppendData(..., aVectorOfChannelData[i]);  // <- this does a resize + std::copy into another vector.
    }
}
```

Comment: You could load everything into memory and then split it. With great advantage of being able to parallelize the split.

Comment: Perhaps look at threading? It could speed the process up. Of course it will depend on your exact situation if it helps (and definitely if it's worth the added complexity).

Comment: @YSC: since memory is going to be the bottleneck, parallelizing it doesn't help. It's probably going to be detrimental.

Comment: Maybe something wrong with your implementation? Show code.

Comment: I think that with a great probability disk I/O will be the bottleneck here anyway. So first write any simple solution, make sure you optimize disk access (read sequentially in big chunks) and profile it. If you will see that indeed disk I/O is a bottleneck, then you will not be able to do anything better.

Answer (score 0):

The limitation here will be the time taken to stream the data off the disk, for that reason you need to focus on reading the data in sequentially and as fast as you can. Minimize any time spent seeking and let the caches between you and the disk work as well as possible by not jumping around in the source file.

Set up a mapping inside your code to send the incoming data to the right places in your data structure and then just read the data from the disk and split it out to the right places. Trying to multi thread or otherwise speed up the processing is likely to make it slower if anything since the bottleneck is almost certainly the disk.

You may be able to speed things up by using a RAM disk to store the data, but copying the data onto the RAM disk will take just as long as reading it in so that will only help if you are reading it repeatedly.